# Store restored files and directories in a separate directory

Tags: shell, tar

I have backup files in the form `backup-date.tar` and these files will be in a directory called `backup`. I am performing a restore by using `tar -xvf backup-date.tar` but the restored file is placed in the backup directory. I want the restored files to be stored in another directory called `restore`. How can I do this?

Comment: `tar -xvf backup.tar -C /path/restore/`

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly:

```
pax -rs ':^backup:restore:' backup-date.tar
```

With GNU `tar`:

```
tar --transform='s:^backup:restore:' -xf backup-date.tar
```

With bsdtar:

```
tar -'s:^backup:restore:' -xf backup-date.tar
```